# Pull unique items & calculations from an array in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a Metrics view in my SwiftUI app. I'm building this so I can track my poker sessions I play. Each Session model looks like this:

```
struct PokerSession: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
let location: String
let game: String
let stakes: String
let date: Date
let profit: Int
let notes: String
let imageName: String
let startTime: Date
let endTime: Date
```

In my Metrics View I would like to iterate through all of the sessions which are stored in an array of type: [PokerSession] that displays a List of all the *unique* locations and their corresponding profit totals. This is how my code looks right now, obviously not working because I'm getting duplicate locations:

```
            List {
            ForEach(viewModel.sessions) { location in
                HStack {
                    Text(location.location)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("$500")
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profit by Location"))
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can grab unique locations and calculate their total profit? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an array of unique locations like this:

```
Array(Set(viewModel.sessions.map { $0.location }))
```

Use this in your `ForEach` to iterate over the `location` strings.

**EDIT**

To calculate the total per `location`, you can simply query your existing data (as described in Yrb's answer):

```
viewModel.sessions.filter({ $0.location == location }).reduce(0) { $0 + $1.profit }
```

Since you already use a view model, I suggest to hide both the creation of the unique locations list and the total profit lookup inside the view model, which will make your UI code much cleaner and more readable.

Also, if you have a lot of `PokerSession` entries, I suggest to generate the data only once and cache it inside the view model, e.g. using a custom data model as described in Rob's answer (or even simpler by generating a dictionary which maps from location string to total profit). The good thing about abstracting the data access away inside the view model is that you can introduce the caching approach later, without changing the UI layer, since you will be able to keep the same access methods and just change their implementation.

Comment: I was going to use a Set, but then how do I calculate those location totals? In other words, say I have a Set of 3 different casino's, but I've visited that same casino 10x and profited $100 each visit. I would need my List to show Casino A: $1,000 profit. Not sure how I get that calculation done.

Comment: @comexbackkid I added the missing description about the total profit calculation. The other answers here already do a good job of explaining this :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd define a new type to store your totals:

```
struct LocationProfit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let location: String
    let profit: Int
}
```

Then you can group all your sessions by location in a dictionary, transform the sessions into a sum of profits, then transform the location and profit totals into our `LocationProfit` structure.

```
let locationProfits = Dictionary(grouping: sessions) { element in
    element.location
}.mapValues { sessionsGroupedByLocation -> Int in
    sessionsGroupedByLocation
        .map { $0.profit }
        .reduce(0, +)
}.map { locationProfitPair in
    LocationProfit(location: locationProfitPair.key, profit: locationProfitPair.value)
}
```

Just stuff the whole conversion into your viewModel and iterate over the locationProfits in your View.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `filter` which will return a filtered array of your `PokerSessions` by `location` then you `reduce` the filtered array to get the sum of your profit like this:

```
viewModel.sessions.filter( { $0.location == location}).reduce(0) { $0 + $1.profit})
```

edit with use case assuming it is in USD:

```
Text("$\(viewModel.sessions.filter( { $0.location == location}).reduce(0) { $0 + $1.profit}))")
```

You could also turn it into a string by add `.description` to the end of it. If you only need to display the data to the user, and don't need it generally available to the app, this is the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: Does this go in my View, or somewhere in the model?

Comment: This goes in your view. It will resolve to an `Int`. I will edit my answer to put a use case in there.

Comment: Thanks for doing that I appreciate it. This is the resulting error I get: Operator function '==' requires that 'PokerSession' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Comment: I was looking back at your code. You had a poor choice in naming the element from the ForEach. You called it `location` when it is actually a `PokerSession`. I would call it `session` and then the comparison becomes `session.location` which make a great deal more sense when reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was borrowed from most of your responses, thank you for the feedback. Below is the final code that worked, was able to avoid creating a dictionary and instead relied on map and reduce.

```
                List {
                ForEach(viewModel.uniqueLocations, id: \.self) { location in
                    HStack {
                        Text(location)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("$" + "\(viewModel.sessions.filter({$0.location == location}).reduce(0) { $0 + $1.profit})")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profit by Location"))
            }
```